# Build go wasm whith Golang script

Tags: go, webassembly

How to make an equivalent script of this one in golang?

```sh
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o res.wasm ./src/main.go
```

I've tried like this

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "build -o res.wasm ./src/main.go")
    cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), "GOOS=js", "GOARCH=wasm")
    cmd.Run()
```

*what ive observed*

- cmd.Run() return `error code 2`
- cmd.Env is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a minor error. You should set each argument separately  for this.

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "-o", "res.wasm", "./src/main.go")
cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), "GOOS=js", "GOARCH=wasm")
cmd.Run()
```

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.